# omnet++ seed set numbers and run number

Tags: c++, omnet++, wifi

I´m facing the following problem :

I´m simulating a wimesh network and a point to multi point in OMNET++ 4.6 using IEEE 802.11g and 11b operating in 2.4GHz and 900 MHz respectively.

I have an HTTP application , which I developed, sending http messages via open sockets.

When running several times with diferente run numbers I see that messages do not arrive to destination. But if it runs on runnumber =0 , all messages arrive.

Can anyone help me to explain , why this may be happening ? Could it be related with the propagation model affecting the received power level ?

Sincerely,

Andre

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation model includes many probabilistic components - at the very least for deciding whether or not a frame is received: to model a packet reception rate of, e.g., 90% your simulation will randomly drop a frame with a 10% probability. Such random effects occur in many parts of any simulation.

This means that not every run will yield the same result: for one simulation, the first five frames might get through, for another already the first frame might be dropped.

This is why you will need to run your simulations many times (with different seeds) to derive a statistically significant result. In OMNeT++ this can be done by setting the `repeat` .ini parameter to, e.g., 100.